# Terraform 0.12 migration - Variables with default object

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to upgrade my TF 0.11 code to 0.12 and i stuck with a variable issue.

In TF 0.11 this blocked worked as expected in the variables.tf file

```
variable "postgres_dbs" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    postgres1 = {
      name_postfix = "postgres",
      enable      = true,
      sku         = "MO_Gen5_16",
      capacity    = "16"
    }
    postgres2 = {
      name_postfix = "postgres-2",
      enable      = false,
      sku         = "MO_Gen5_16",
      capacity    = "16"
    }
    postgres3 = {
      name_postfix = "postgres-3",
      enable      = false,
      sku         = "MO_Gen5_16",
      capacity    = "16"
    }
    postgres4 = {
      name_postfix = "postgres-4",
      enable       = false,
      sku          = "MO_Gen5_16",
      capacity     = "16"
    }
    postgres5 = {
      name_postfix = "postgres-5",
      enable       = false,
      sku          = "MO_Gen5_16",
      capacity     = "16"
    }
    postgres6 = {
      name_postfix = "postgres-6",
      enable       = false,
      sku          = "MO_Gen5_16",
      capacity     = "16"
    }
    postgres7 = {
      name_postfix = "postgres-7",
      enable       = false,
      sku          = "MO_Gen5_16",
      capacity     = "16"
    }
    postgres8 = {
      name_postfix = "postgres-8",
      enable       = false,
      sku          = "MO_Gen5_16",
      capacity     = "16"
    }
  }
}
```

After running the terraform 012upgrade command ( It finished with no errors )
TF changed the block to use

```
variable "postgres_dbs" {
  type = map(string)
```

But the error when running terraform validate is :

```
This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint:
element "postgres6": string required.
```

Any advice ?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you try changing `map(string)` to `map(map)`?

Comment: Tried and got this error:  144:   type = map(map)

The map type constructor requires one argument specifying the element type.

Comment: It looks like it's actually `map(object)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update and fine-tune your type specification like the following:

```
type = map(object({
  name_postfix = string
  enable       = bool
  sku          = string
  capacity     = string
}))
```

Ideally you could specify the `capacity` object argument as a `number` instead, but you are casting your inputs to that argument as a `string`, so that would cause an incompatibility unless you specified the input as its natural `number` type.